# Did original Scripture say Noah was a "son" of 600 years when the water landed?

Tags: genesis, noah, mathematics

Clearly most English Bibles say Noah was 600 years old when the water landed. [Gen 7:6](http://biblehub.com/genesis/7-6.htm).

It’s intriguing that one Bible in English differs quite a bit from others, if only in the words written. That is the Young Literal Translation [Gen 7:6](http://biblehub.com/genesis/7-6.htm):

> and Noah is a ***son of*** six hundred years, and the deluge of waters ***hath been*** upon the earth

Beyond the YLT, others along the way have had “son” or "som" mentioned for Gen 7:6.
E.G.[Pulpit Commentary](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/pulpit/genesis/7.htm), 
[Barnes' Notes on the Bible](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/genesis/7-6.htm), 
[NASB Lexicon](http://biblehub.com/lexicon/genesis/7-6.htm)

Did original Scripture say Noah was a **"son"** of 600 years when the water landed? That could cause a big difference in time yet explain a math concern. Did it have the words “hath been” also?

Comment: Haven't we had this question several times already?

Comment: @fdb I‘ve changed the question slightly, and removed a lot of detail. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gen. 7:6 says that Noah was (literally) ‘the son of 600 years’ ( בן שש מאות שנה) when the flood began. This is an idiom in Hebrew, and in other Semitic languages (e.g. Arabic and Syriac) meaning ‘600 years old’, that is: in the year beginning with his 600th birthday.

You can compare the Syriac translation (Pšīttā) of John 8:57, which has ܥܕ݂ܰܟ݁ܺܝܠ ܒ݁ܰܪ ܚܰܡܫܺܝܢ ܫܢܺܝܢ ܠܳܐ ܗ݈ܘܰܝܬ݁ literally: ‘you have not yet been the son of fifty years’, translating πεντήκοντα ἔτη οὔπω ἔχεις literally: ‘you do not yet have fifty years’, that is: you have not yet celebrated your 50th birthday.

In Arabic too ibnu khamsiina sanatan (literally: ‘son of 50 years’) means ‘50 years old’, i.e., between one’s 50th and 51st  birthday.

Comment: Thank you. Here's what I still have as a problem; it has Gen 7:6 being the one verse that doesn't fit the others mathematically. When the floodgates were opened, early in his 600th year of life, only 599 years, 1 month, 16 days of his life had gone by.  By the time all was dry again, only 600 years, 1 month, 26 days of his life had gone by. His being 600 years old when the water first landed doesn't fit there.

Comment: @JohnMartin, I'm not certain why you subtract 1 from each part of his age (600th year, 2nd month, 17th day -> 599 years, 1 month, and 16 days).

Comment: @Frank Luke    If a child were born exactly 1 year ago (yesterday), today he's into his 2nd year, 1st month, 1st day after birth.  Therefore, he’s had 1 year, 0 months, and 0 days go by.

Comment: Yes, he is in his second year but he is only one year old.

Comment: @JohnMartin, I think you are forcing idioms to be more exact then they need to be.

Comment: @Frank Luke Q: Would it make more sense to discuss this in the library? (Then I could delete even this comment). The reason I'm taking it to even the day is because the story does.

Comment: @JohnMartin Yeah, let's do that.

Comment: @fdb I agree with your last comment; there I was explaining simply by using birth forward. Starting from conception when life begins though, (and assuming it's 9 months before birth), when the child has had exactly 3 months go by since birth, today he's into his 2nd year, 1st month, 1st day of...life.  We'd say he became 3 months old yesterday; today he's started into his 2nd year of life.

Comment: Does this idiom occur somewhere else in the Old Testament?